What is the fastest (fast time response) peltier module commercially available and where can I buy it?
I am searching for a peltier module which has a time response of at least 0,1 seconds. I looked around in the market but this is not usually a characteristic shared by the manufacturer in the data sheet. Anyone who knows where I can find it?

PS: the peltier module will be used for cooling, with the cold side ranging between 30 and -5 Celsius

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics as a natural science.

Why is this question closed? In physics.stackexchange.com/tour it is stated that we can ask about "Experimental technology used in physics or astronomy". The question is borderline off-topic, but imo doesn't deserve to be closed!

This question has been asked a number of times on Electrical Engineering StackExchange. E.G. Is it possible to obtain very small Peltier modules with fast response times?. you might also look here - How to Select a Peltier Module
